# Incorrect syntax coloring for bash $#

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

**Background:** In Bash, $# represents the number of arguments, and `#` starts a comment.

Consider the following Bash script:

```bash
# This is a comment
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    echo $1
    shift
done
```

Note that the syntax coloring by StackExchange here is incorrect! The `#` in `$#` is being treated as a comment marker.

Vim, for example, gets it right:

[image: Correct syntax highlighting]

Can the StackOverflow syntax highlighting engine be improved to fix this?

(This is a partial [cross-post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209632/37357).)

---

<sup>Keywords because searching for symbols is a pain: dollar hash, dollar octothorpe, dollar pound, dollar number.</sup>

Comment: See the linked FAQ, specifically the *How do I report a bug or request a new language?* section. Report issues with highlighting to the Google Prettify project.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks very much.